# How to Increase column count on magento product category page

Tags: magento2

Is there any way to increase column count in magento product category page.
Default it listed 4 product in a row. I need 5 Products in a row

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find below CSS styles in **`vendor/magento/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/module/_listings.less`**

```
.products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/3 }
.page-layout-1column .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/3 }
.page-layout-3columns .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/3 }
.page-products .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/3 }
.page-products.page-layout-1column .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/3 }
.page-products.page-layout-3columns .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/3 }
```

So you can copy this file into your theme directory, then change those widths like below.

```
.products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/5 }
.page-layout-1column .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/5 }
.page-layout-3columns .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/5 }
.page-products .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/5 }
.page-products.page-layout-1column .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/5 }
.page-products.page-layout-3columns .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/5 }
```

Comment: It's not working . Im using enterprise version . any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can add below css lines in your custom theme's css here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/custom.css

If you want to display **5 items** then you can use like this..

```
.page-products .products-grid .product-item {
    width : calc((100% - 6%)/5) !important;
}
```

Please check below screenshot..

[image]

If you want to display **3 items** then you can use like this..

```
.page-products .products-grid .product-item {
    width : calc((100% - 6%)/3) !important;
}
```

Please check below screenshot..

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Did you tried this ?